# Pass TempData to ActionFilter RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, .net-core, viewbag, action-filter, tempdata

I want to set a ViewBag for second an action from the first action by using ActionFilter.

In the first Action i do the following :

```
TempData["Test"] = "Test"; 
return RedirectToAction("Action2", new { values = values });
```

Then in IActionFilter :

```
public class HelpertestActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
        if (controller != null)
        {
            if (controller.TempData["Test"] != null)
            {
                controller.ViewBag.Notification = controller.TempData["Test"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in ActionFilter OnActionExecuting, TempData["Test"] is always null.

I have followed this [article](https://schwabencode.com/blog/2017/09/25/ASPNETCore-Using-Tempdata)

Comment: I am already trying to get TempData in OnActionExecuting method. But i is still null.

Comment: Are you using `services.AddSession()` and `app.UseSession()` in your `Startup` configuration?

Comment: Yes, i am using both in my Startup configuration.

Comment: @TristanSébillet Try `TempData.Keep` or `TempData.Peek` and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Tried both and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try, there is no errors in my code, except in the startup configuration.

In Startup.Configure() the app.UseCookiePolicy() has to be after app.UseMVC() to work as expected.